# Making UIAccelerometer work more than once when switching views

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiview, accelerometer

I need help with a problem and not sure how to fix it. Basically I have a view which switches to another view by using the accelerometer, the problem is it only works once. When I go back to the first view, the accelerometer won't work again until i rebuild the project.

This is the method I use:

```
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration {     
float aX = ABS(acceleration.x);
float aY = ABS(acceleration.y);
float aZ = ABS(acceleration.z);
if(sqrt(aX*aX+aY*aY+aZ*aZ)>1.5f)
{
    SecondViewController *screen = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    //screen.words = self.easy;
    [self presentModalViewController:screen animated:YES];
    [screen release];
self.accelerometer.delegate = nil;  
}
```

Any kind of help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you set self.accelerometer.delegate = nil; when you switch to other view ? May be it is causing problem.

Comment: If I don't set it, it will give me an error because I'm trying to launch a transition while the current transition is still running, because the "accelerometer:didAccelerate" function is getting called each time.

Comment: Thank while coming back to the original view are you again assigning accelerometer delegate ? i.e. either in viewDidLoad/viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear whatever suits, you can put self.accelerometer.delegate = self like that. I guess this should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a BOOL to temporarily disable the accelerometer handling when you present the new view controller and avoid calling self.accelerometer.delegate = nil

Once the modal transition is done, you can re-enable the accelerometer handling

Edit - 
Example:

```
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration {     

if(accelerometerEnabled) {

     //... the accelerometer data handling goes here
}
```

Also, it looks like I did not understand all of the question originally - you'll also need to reset the accelerometer delagate to whatever view controller you want to use to handle the acceleration data. That (second) view controller will have to have the -(void)accelerometer delegate method also.

Alternatively, you could handle the acceleration data in a root view controller and make your views subviews of that root view. That would be cleaner, as you would never have to change which controller is handling the acceleration.

Comment: Can you show me an example on how to do this? I'm not quite sure.